# Regex patterns to distinguish four digit numbers

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I have a c# application where it accepts a 4 digit extension number and sets up a mask for it. I have a situation where two different masks need to be applied depending on the number.

```
First: If the number starts with 47 or 5 return mask A.

Second: If the number starts with 6 or 55 return mask B.
```

So I setup my Regex this way and I am not sure why its getting set wrong.

```
//Here I am trying to say, anything that start with 47 or 5 with the next 3 digits taking any number
Match first = Regex.Match(num, "^(47|(5[0123456789]{3}))");

//anything that start with 6 or 55 with the next 2 digits taking numbers 0-5
Match secong = Regex.Match(num, "(6|55[123450]{2})");
```

If I give use the above with input num=5850 or num=5511 it will be true for both but clearly 5850 should use Mask A and 5511 should use Mask B

How do I fix this??

Thanks!

Comment: Start with testing for 6 or 55 first, if it fails, move to check 47 or 5.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to do this in one regexp instead of adding a bunch of `if (input.StartsWith("47")) { ... }` clauses?

Comment: Can you move the position of your two matches so that it matches 55 before it tries to match 5?

Comment: @millimoose it does not need to be within one exp but I will be returning the same thing for both if stmts

Comment: @Andrew I can flip their order but that i'd rather not to do that because I do not want two exp to be true

Comment: Regardless of the order 55 will match both expressions because the one searching for 5 at the beginning also matches 3 subsequent numbers, one or more of which can also be 5 meaning 55 is valid for both.

Comment: So, your rule is `if (inputString.StartsWith("47") || (inputString.StartsWith("5" && ! inputString.StartsWith("55"))) { ... }`.

Comment: A more extensible solution would be to make a `List<Tuple<string, Regex>>` that maps prefixes to masks. Sort this list by the "key" length in descending order (longest to shortest), iterate over list, return the first "value" for which `inputString.StarsWith(key)`. You could also make this `O(1)` by making a state machine handle recognizing the prefix but that's probably excessive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should do it for you.

This matches any 4 digit number starting with 47 or 5, excluding 5 as the second digit.

```
^(47|5([0-4]|[6-9]))\d{2}$
```

This matches any 4 digit number starting with 6 or 55.

```
^(6\d|55)\d{2}$
```

Comment: Thanks that did what I wanted!

Comment: Your question states "If the number starts with 6 or 55 return mask B.", but later in your regex comments you state "6 or 55 with the next 2 digits taking numbers 0-5". I know you've accepted already, but could your clairify this please? Should the last two digits be anything, or just 0-5?

Comment: They should only take 0-5 because we do not have extensions with the last two digits being any number... but that is not an issue since it will not try to input them anyway

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following...

```
Match first = Regex.Match(num, "^(47[0-9]{2}|5[0-9-[5]]{1}[0-9]{2})");

Match second = Regex.Match(num, "^(6[0-9]{3}|55[0-9]{2})");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will cover you. note you can use \d for 0-9, a range for 0-5, and you left the boundary indicator (^) off the second one. Note I didn't use a range or \d for the first part of the first one, because you don't want to match 55. Notice also the grouping.

```
//anything that start with 47 or 5 with the next 3 digits taking any number (but not 55!)
Match first = Regex.Match(num, "^((47|5[012346789])\d{2})");

//anything that start with 6 or 55 with the next 2 digits taking numbers 0-5
Match secong = Regex.Match(num, "^((6|55)[0-5]{2})");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should use 4 regular expressions

```
/^47\d{3}/

/^5\d{4}/

/^6\d{4}/

/^55\d{3}/
```

notice how numbers that begin with `55` are a match for both of your cases, but the reverse doesn't work for numbers that begin with `5` you should use that fact to distinguish between them

---

if you want to combine regular expressions, than that's fine

```
/(^47\d{3})|(^5\d{4})/
```

note: you might also want to use the end of input anchor: `$` or a word boundary or negative look-ahead to match the end of output too.